# How to make a clickable link based on users login details

Tags: php

I have created a login system (with help from people on this site) that redirects a logged in user to several pages that only they have access to based on their login information. When navigating the site they will also have access to other pages that all logged in users have access to.

This information is in a msql database and uses php redirect. The system has a small area to show a logged in users name and a logout option. Using sessions this is shown on whatever page the user views whether it is their personal page or a general page open to any logged in user. What I would like to do is to create a “go back to personal page” link (in the same panel as the logout and user name) so whoever is logged in will have a quick link back to their personal page.

I am quite new to PHP and I am sure there is a very simple way to uses the login information and the redirect function to create a clickable text link to achieve this but I have not found a way to do this. I would appreciate help from anyone who could point me in the right direction.

Comment: It might be useful to show some code...

Comment: I have tried this code, see below but I get access denied code 403. The logon system and redirects correctly when the initially logon. But when I use this code to redirect them back to their personal page I get the error report.
<p><a href="<?php $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);$_SESSION['fname'] = $result['fname'];$redirect = trim($result['redirect']);

 if ($redirect == '') {
        echo "No redirect value was set!";
    } else {
        header('Location: ' . $redirect);
        exit;
    }

?>">Go back to personal page</a>&nbsp;</p>

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how the personal page is setup. But no matter what, you should need nothing more than a HTML link...

```
<a href="personal.php">Go back to personal page</a>
```

where `personal.php` is the name of the file that you want to send the user to. Now if you do things with the user's ID, you might have something like

```
<a href="personal.php?userId=<?php echo $userid; ?>">Go back to personal page</a>
```

where `$userid` is the variable that contains the user's ID.

So essentially, how do you currently view the user's profile? Put that link in an `<a>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your help, sorry for not responding earlier I did not get an e-mail to let me know my question had an answer. Thanks again I will try that with the redirect function.